# How do I query a MySQL database via Linq in an ASP.NET MVC 3 app?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to query a MySQL database from my C# ASP.NET MVC 3 application, and I figure it's best done via Linq. I'm not sure how it's done however, my current impression is that only Microsoft SQL is directly supported by Linq. So how can I query MySQL via Linq in the ASP.NET MVC 3 context (in C#)?

**EDIT:**
Note I would definitely prefer that any dependencies were installable with NuGet, as all my current dependencies are installed this way.

Comment: aknuds1 It looks like Kellerman Software has a MySQL LINQ Provider:
https://www.kellermansoftware.com/p-47-net-data-access-layer.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use SauceDB, it has support for sql server, sqlite, postgre, and mysql.  Among other feature it does support linq style queries.

http://sauce.codeplex.com

Disclamer: I Wrote it.

Comment: Is it easy to use in comparison to DBLinq (or other relevant alternatives)?

Comment: I cant really speak for dblinq cause I have never used that particular one, however, what really sets it apart from NHibernate or L2Sql is what little is required.  For an example of the linq query see http://sauce.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Query%20Syntax&referringTitle=Linq%20Support.  There is also a pretty comprehensive example on nuget here http://nuget.org/List/Packages/SauceDB.Sample

Comment: I was able to apply SauceDB successfully, and am now going with that :)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, LINQ to SQL is for SQL Server.  However, the LINQ provider mechanism is open, there is a MySQL version called DBLinq:

http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/LINQ-To-MySQL.aspx

You could always use an ORM tool like NHibernate, which works against MySQL.  NHibernate then has it's own LINQ support:

http://ayende.com/blog/4083/nhibernate-linq-1-0-released

Comment: Would you recommend one over the other? Mind that any dependencies should preferably be installable with NuGet.

Comment: @aknuds if you are doing simple things or only have a small data model , I'd go for the straight LINQ.  If your model gets more involved, I'd go for NHibernate for other features.  I know NHibernate is distributed via Nuget, not sure about the DBLinq.